# Send PHP Form to Different Emails Based on Radio Buttons

Tags: php, forms, radio-button, contacts

I've seen a number of questions similar to this one, but since I'm new to PHP I'm having trouble putting the function in the right place. I've got something cobbled together in PHP and HTML but I seem to be missing something around the `$radio` area. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$radio = isset($_POST['radio']) ? $_POST['radio'] : 'default';
switch ($radio) {
case 'Eval CH':
$to = 'blah@blah.com';
    break;
case 'Eval ELL':
$to = 'sigh@sigh.com';
    break;
}
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: WAC Site';  
$subject = 'WAC Contact Message';
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
echo '<p>Either you are a robot, or you are very, very bad at math.</p>';
}
?>
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="contact_options.php">

<label>Name</label><br>
<input name="name" placeholder="Type Here"><br>
<br>        
<label>Email</label><br>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here"><br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Eval CH" value="to">Email Blah<br>
<input type="radio" name="Eval ELL" value="to">Email Sigh<br>
<label>Message</label><br>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea><br>
<br>
<label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
<input name="human" placeholder="Type Here"><br />         
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"><br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$_POST['radio']` doesn't exist the way you have your form setup.  Only things with a `name=` are passed to the `$_POST` superglobal.

Change the condition in your PHP handler to this:

`$radio = isset($_POST['Eval CH']) ? $_POST['Eval CH'] : $_POST['Eval ELL'];`

But, you really have 3 conditions here:

```
$_POST['Eval CH']
$_POST['Eval ELL']
None selcted
```

So really your shorthand doesn't work here because you need

```
if
elseif
else
```

So you really need more advanced handling, like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['Eval CH'])) {
   $to = 'blah@blah.com';
}
elseif (isset($_POST['Eval ELL'])) {
   $to = 'sigh@sigh.com';
}
else {
   $to = 'default@default.com';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons should have a common name and proper value. They should look like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="contact_option" value="Eval CH">Email Blah<br>
<input type="radio" name="contact_option" value="Eval ELL">Email Sigh<br>
```

Then, in your post you can replace your line with this:

```
$radio = isset($_POST['contact_option']) ? $_POST['contact_option'] : 'default';
```

Also, `if ($_POST['submit']) { }` should go around that whole section of code when you post, not just checking if you're human.

Comment: This won't work either. With two items named the same thing you are losing one or the other when submitting the info to the server.

Comment: Yes, I know that. These are radio buttons not checkboxes. This is what it should be. One or the other. Why the downvote?

Comment: My bad. I guess I shouldn't be trying to help others with their code when I'm so tired.

Comment: Sorry, I can't. SO doesn't allow it after a certain amount of time.  Tried to do it this morning before I left but even then it was too late.

Answer (score 0):

try to reverse name and value in your radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="to" value="Eval CH">Email Blah<br>
<input type="radio" name="to" value="Eval ELL">Email Sigh<br>
```

Comment: That won't make a difference. Can always adapt to either in the PHP handler itself.